# creating android search view which also holds the selected items

Tags: android

I would like to implement a search view which display selected items like in gmail app.

[image]

like this.

could somebody tell me how can i do it in android.Is there any library available to create a view like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a library that does what you are looking for.  It may not be exact but it is close to what you are showing in the image.  Try to be more specific within your question.

https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips